# add record and Manipulating recordset to contain formulas

Tags: excel, vb6, ado, recordset

basic details:
oracle, vb6 and excel,  using ADO to fetch recordsets.

I am facing a problem in manipulating the recordset when i add a new record at the end of the recordset. the last record should contain the formulas such as count of, say, column2, sum of values in column3, and division of sum(col3) and col2

original columns in recordset

CLIENT                end of this column should display Total

PRINCIPAl            end of this column should display average(Principal)

GROSS_LIQ_RATE       end of this column should display average(gross)/sum(principal)

when I am adding the recordset, it gives an error
i am adding like this:

```
.AddNew     .[columnname] = Sum(rst.Fields(1))      .Update
```

thanks for looking into this.

Comment: your question is understandable... please edit your question and explain us what you have, what you intend to do and what you tried and where is the error (provided you give us the full code you built)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't beliveve you can use `Sum()` in that way. You would use `application.worksheetfunction.sum()` since sum is not a vba function.

Secondly I don't think `rst.fields(1)` will return all values in the field. You would need to iterate through the recordset summing `rst.fields(1).value` for each record.

From a design standpoint.... all of the values you are looking for could easily be calculated via SQL directly, I don't see any reason for pulling the data into a recordset to preform these operations.

Comment: i will try to elaborate more:      Lets say we have a have report type which displays principal amount for year 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010. The corresponding values are in 3rd field in the recordset. so the values will dumped into excel as 
FYPeriod    col2           Principal
2007        somevalue         230000
2008        somevalue         431280
2009        somevalue         343455
Total                       sum(all of above in Principal)
Is there a way to achieve this in sql only?

Comment: To me it seems to be less effort to write a second SQL statement that Omits the year number all together (therby displaying the total of all years).